# google sheet script how to get last changed date in cell history

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, version-control

In Google Sheets, you can see the cell history manually.

How can I get the last changed date of a cell by using a script?

e.g.

```
var cellLastChanged = range.getCell(1, 1).*getlastchanged()*;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the history of a cell cannot be directly retrieved. So as a workaround, how about using [Revisions of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions)? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this as of now.

However, there is a [Feature Request](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151809) for this.

Also, as [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) suggested, you can try using the [Revisions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) from Drive API.